# Number of Jordan Blocks

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Determine the Jordan Normal Form over $\Bbb Q$ of the following matrix.

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&1&1&0\\0&2&0&0&0\\-1&3&0&0&0\\0&-1&1&0&1\\1&-1&0&-1&0\end{bmatrix}$$

The characteristic polynomial is $char_A(X)=(X-2)(X^2+1)^2$
[image]

[image]

Why is the number of Jordan block $0$ at $k=1, dim(ker(L_{A_2}^k))=2$???

Doesn't the number of blocks depends on the dimension of the kernel? i.e. because $dim(ker(A_2))=2$ there should be 2 Jordan blocks?

Comment: assuming your characteristic polynomial is right, $A$ does not even have a Jordan form over $\Bbb{Q}$ (it doesn't split so no Jordan form).

Comment: this is the official solution. And they mix the rational canonical form into it.

Comment: I didn't read the rest of the solution; the question doesn't make sense. If anything the only answer which should be given is "The Jordan form doesn't exist over $\Bbb{Q}$". Do you perhaps have a typo in the matrix (and hence the characteristic polynomial)?

Comment: no everything is correct, the jordon form doesnt exisit over $\Bbb Q$ so they want you to use the rational canonical form for the irreducible polynomial part. In this course the rational canonical form is a part of the jordon normal form..confused me too

Comment: No, that isn't a rational canonical form. Note that the second sub-matrix in the first block row of $B^{-1}AB$ is not zero. I think whoever wrote this exercise was thinking about [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form#A_rational_normal_form_generalizing_the_Jordan_normal_form) generalisation of Jordan form as described in Wikipedia.

Comment: @user1551 ouhhhh because i read a few rational canonical form examples and the computtation was basically the same...